# Do RAID 1 drives have to be exactly the same size?

Tags: raid, windows-server-2008

Do drives have to be exactly the same size for RAID 1?

The RAID option is greyed out—some research says that the drives need to be the same size, but do they have to be *exactly* the same size (to the byte) or is there some leeway (maybe a percentage)?

I have two 1TB drives, different manufacturers.  One is 953980 Mb and the other is 953740 Mb, so both claim to be 1TB but are 240mb different.

Server specs are:

- Server Dell PowerEdge T310
- Running Windows 2008, 64bit
- Raid Controller Dell SAS 6/iR Adaptor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most RAID controllers probably won't let you use two different sized hard drives. However if it does, you will be limited to the amount of space of your smallest hard drive.

Comment: I don't think this is answering the question though; the point is, both hard drives are 1TB, but when it comes down to bytes, vary only marginally. I wonder if this matters

Comment: I will resize the larger drive on the weekend so they are the same and then see if Windows will allow me to mirror.  I has assumed that 2 1Tb drives would actually be the same size - we learn these things slowly sometimes!

Comment: Most likely no.

Comment: @DaveRook from what I've read, they're both 1TB drives - so I highly doubt bytes will matter to a RAID controller. Without knowing what RAID controller is being used (software/hardware) I can merely speculate based on basic functionality of RAID.

Comment: @Cole, ah, I'm slowly catching up... So, in the case of the OP, you're saying that the size issue is probably not the matter here as they only differ by a small amount.

Comment: @DaveRook correct. However, there's always that catch depending on what software/hardware he's using. Without more information, I can only give an answer based on how RAID typically works.

Comment: @SydxPages, please do let us know if this fixes it, as they are 240 mb out from each other.

Comment: Will get another outage on the weekend to try & will update.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay - answered!  Yes, it was due to the minimal size difference.  The larger of the 2 drives was the one that had the data on it to be mirrored.  It's now synchronising...

Comment: To clarify, you were able to resize the partition of the drive with the data (the larger capacity drive) to match the capacity of the second drive with less capacity? So, perhaps it is just a matter of resizing the partition to match before setting RAID 1.

Comment: you can set coercion if drives are not identical size... most controllers have that option.

Answer (score 0):

On MS products the option is greyed out if:

1. One of the drives is the boot drive (not sure the logic here but you
   could do this in NT4)
2. One of the drives has a pagefile (Do not move the page file to a USB
   drive)
3. If the drive speeds are to far apart (do not mirror a 10k drive to a
   5400 spin drive)
4. If the drives are not dynamic. (not sure why non, dynamic drives
   mirrored in NT4 just fine)
5. If the security policy prevents it (prevents users from shooting
   their own foot)
6. If a GPO adjusted the security policy to prevent it
7. If SCCM, SMS, MOM, or configuration manager enforced a policy on it
8. there is probably a dozen more reasons