# Does a mirroring RAID require same-size HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, raid, raspberry-pi

I am trying to think of a Raspberry Pi RAID for file storage.

Reason: I have several HDDs each with some older backups, which doesn't really make sense. I am trying to consolidate the backups with a file server Pi setup.

So I have this couple of existing (external USB) HDDs, could I use those for that? They are already pretty full...they are of different type and size...

Or should I better buy two identical disks and start from scratch?

Comment: Short answer is no.. but please provide RasPi specs.  Raspi1 is not Raspi 4.  Please provide [which RAID configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels) as this will help people help you.  I myself would go with two identical disks regardless as you will end up at the speed and size of the weakest link.  This is true for all RAID configurations I believe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do RAID 1 drives have to be exactly the same size?](https://superuser.com/questions/527519/do-raid-1-drives-have-to-be-exactly-the-same-size)

Comment: I was thinking of RAID1 (mirroring), which I put in the title but did not clarify, sorry.

Comment: @harrymc sort of, that link answers my question. It kinda feels it MAY work, but my drives are pretty different, so most probably I should go with new identical drives....

Comment: Yes, otherwise you risk having unusable disk space.